# How to declare a variable with nested templates?

Tags: c++11, templates

For a personal project, I want to create a generic graph.
I have created 2 classes: a class OrientedNode and a class ClassicArrow.

Here are the class file:
-Node Class File

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//BEGIN OF THE CLASS CLASSICNODE:MOTHER CLASS OF EVERY TYPE OF NODE
class ClassicNode{
    protected:
        unsigned int nodeId;    
    public:
        //Constructor
        ClassicNode();
        ClassicNode(unsigned int NodeId);
        //Getters
        unsigned int getId()const;
        //Operator
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream, const ClassicNode& N){
            return outputStream << N.getId()<<std::endl;
        }
        bool operator ==(const ClassicNode& N);
};

//BEGIN OF THE CLASS ORIENTEDNODE:
//  -IT INHERITS THE CLASS NODE
//  -IT REPRESENTS THE NODE IN A ORIENTED GRAPHE

template <typename ARROW> class OrientedNode: public ClassicNode{
    protected:
        std::vector<ARROW> listArrowsIn;
        std::vector<ARROW> listArrowsOut;
    public:
        //Constructor
        OrientedNode();
        OrientedNode(unsigned int NodeId);
       //Getter
       std::vector<ARROW> getListArrowIn()const;
       std::vector<ARROW> getListArrowOut()const;
       //Manipulation
       void addArrowIn(const ARROW& A);
       void addArrowOut(const ARROW& A);
};
```

-Arc Class File:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
template <typename NODE> class ClassicArrow
{
    protected:
        unsigned int origineNodeId;//Id of the node where the arrow begin
        unsigned int destinationNodeId;//Id of the node where the arrow end
        float distance;
        NODE* targetNode;//Pointer to the node where the arrow end
    public:
        //Constructor
        ClassicArrow();
        ClassicArrow(const ClassicArrow<NODE>& A);
        ClassicArrow(unsigned int OrigineNodeId,unsigned int DestinationNodeId,float Distance,NODE* TargetNode);
        //Getters
        unsigned int getOrigineNodeId()const;
        unsigned int getDestinationNodeId()const;
        float getDistance()const;
        NODE* getTargetNode()const;
        //Operator
        void operator=(const ClassicArrow<NODE>& A);
        NODE& operator*(void);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream, const ClassicArrow<NODE>& A){
            return outputStream <<"IdBegin="<<A.getOrigineNodeId()<< "IdEnd="<<A.getDestinationNodeId()<<"distance="<<A.getDistance()<<std::endl;
        }
};
```

The OrientedNode class and the ClassicArrow class are nested together.
I want to declare a OrientedNode variable with template class parameter ClassicArrow (the ligne to file in the main file). How can I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "ClassicArrow.h"
#include "ClassicNode.h"


int main() {
    //Code for a Oriented Node variable declaration
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do and where you are stuck. Please add more elevant information to the post. Post a [mcve] if you can.

Comment: Do you know how i can post the interesting part of my project?

Comment: You create a small independent program that does nothing -- `int main() {}`. Then you keep adding to it until it breaks.

Comment: Do I do that in the comment field? Is it possible in stackoverflow to upload a zip-file with only the interesting part of my program?

Comment: No, you have to try to create a [mcve] that can be posted in textual form. See [ask] for more on the subject.

Comment: Ok thank you, i have edited it. Is it clearer?

Comment: @RSahu whoops 

Comment: It seems you want to use a class like `OrientedNode<ClassicArrow<OrientedNode<ClassicArrow...>>>`. You cannot. Your design is unworkable. You would need to change it to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Yes it is exactly like this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have another question, can i declare a template typename for a template. Ex: template <typename ARROW<OrientedNode>> class OrientedNode;